# How can I show if a user is online in express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am making a chat app and would like to add the functionality of showing an online/offline symbol next to users. How can I do this reliably with minimum number of srever requests and database writes?

One way I found was to update a `lastSeenAt` field in the user document every time that user requests a page and use this to indicate whether the user is online/offline. Another way is to ping the server from the client side at fixed intervals of time and then update the lastSeenAt field.

Both theses ways would require a lot of database writes and/or server requests. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You have to push data from your server to the clients upon change, with something like web-sockets or server sent events. [socket.io](https://socket.io) is a popular tool for implementing such functionally.

With socket.io or specifically websockets you could track the if a client is connected or not and have a flag in database that tracks whenever a client connects or 
disconnects(keep in mind, the client might be having multiple connections(multiple devices, or even browser tabs), so if one connection disconnect he still might be online.

Assuming you will have multiple state-less webservers(common practice), then once a client connects or disconnects you want to notify other interested clients, then you should a use a pubsub pattern to notify other servers which will notify their connected clients respectively. There's a lot of implementations such as Redis, zeromq, AWS SNS, GCP Cloud Pubsub. You could even use [MongoDB with tailable cursors](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/pubsub-with-mongodb) as your pubsub.

However this might mean a lot of constant connections to your server, so this might hurt your scaliblity. If it proves to be to expensive for you then your `lastSeenAt` approach with some sane polling. You can find out which works better with your setup by just running some experiments.

If database writes and requests worries, you could always throw more servers at it. You could have a microservice specifically for this so your main server wouldn't be affected much and also you could have a database specifically for this. If performance worries you, you can use a in-memory database.

Also you can also have some caching in your servers with simple time based invalidation or you can sync the online/offline data between your servers with a pubsub pattern.

I would suggest try to make your setup as simple as possible, and you can run experiments to see how it handles your expected traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Express.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express.io) where you can combine HTTP calls with sockets. (the best method for real-time communication is Sockets).